# Altering PostGIS table with X and Y values of lines

Tags: postgis, sql, update-query

I have a PostGIS table of a road network. The roads have topology and have been split with pgr_nodeNetwork. I also have source and target columns for each of the road segment. I want to be able to perform pgRouting with MapServer and OpenLayers. So I assume that the click in the OpenLayers WMS service will send coordinates to the server. Is there any way to alter the PostGIS table and ad x and y columns (like x1, y1 and x2,y2) without having to do it manually ?

Answer (score 1):

OK I've got it. First I added the columns x1,y1 and x2,y2 as:

```
ALTER TABLE road_network
  ADD COLUMN x1 FLOAT8,
  ADD COLUMN y1 FLOAT8,
  ADD COLUMN x2 FLOAT8,
  ADD COLUMN y2 FLOAT8;
```

and then add the values like this:

```
UPDATE roads_network
SET x1 = ST_X(ST_Startpoint(geom)),
  y1 = ST_Y(ST_Startpoint(geom)),
  x2 = ST_X(ST_Endpoint(geom)),
  y2 = ST_Y(ST_Endpoint(geom));
```

That should do  :-)

Comment: edited to make more concise and efficient.